# Why does Magento show out-of-stock products when I have inventory?

Tags: magento

Sometimes, when you try to create an order in Magento, it may say that your product is out of stock. See the error message below.

[image]

But, If you go look at the Catalog->ManageProducts section, you see that this product has a non-zero inventory quantity specified.

[image]

So, even though you have 40 units in stock, if you specify this product as out-of-stock in that dropdown, you are going to get that warning message I mentioned at the top of this article.

Mainly, Bundle product gets out-of-stock. we add to cart 2 times than automatically gets out of stock. See image below:
[image]

Thanks in Advance. Please solve this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the deafult feature of Magento and this allows you to set product "OutOfStock" independently from the product quantity. But in case of inventory, if the invertory is zero then Magento changes the status of "Stock Availability" as "Out of Stock".

Comment: stock is greater than zero, even though it shows "Out of Stock". I have checked all modules that does't affects to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix it:
You go to:
`Catalog => Manage Products =>` You select just the products where you have stocks (i use the quantity filter searching 1 to 100) `=> The you press search => Select ALL the products => The you select the tab "Update atributes" from "Actions"=> Press Send => Go to "Inventory" Tab => Scroll down to "stock availability" => Check "GLOBAL" => Then select "IN STOCK" and SAVE`.
If you have 2k products in stock like me, you will `wait 4-5` minutes to update all product.

Done. Now you have all products with stock "in stock", available on your site.